# Why do Kotlin Lambda functions not execute when called?

Tags: kotlin

In the following code I have 2 functions - first one wrapped in a lambda body and the other without.

```
fun first() = { println("first")}
fun second() = println("second")

first()
second()
```

Only `second()` prints - why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is a function that returns a function. What happens in fact is that `first()` returns another function that prints "first", but doesn't execute it.

To do this you have to call it by adding another set of of parenthesis:

```
first()()
// Or
val resultOfFirst = first()
resultOfFirst()
```

This happens because the `=` sign for functions is analogous to a return statement and when you wrap things in `{}` you're in fact creating a lambda. Hence, first returns a lambda, but doesn't execute it

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple. Check types of those:

```
fun first(): () -> Unit = { println("first") }
fun second(): Unit = println("second")
```

So, when you call `first` you get lamda expression. To invoke this function use `.invoke()` (or simply `()`):

```
first().invoke()
// or
first()()
```

Second is obvious - it's executed on call.

Answer (score 2):

The function `first` returns a function `{ println("first")}`.

Calling `first()` does nothing - not even its return argument is catched.

Without a lambda an equivalent would be, maybe it is easier to understand it in this form:

```
fun firstWithoutLambda() = fun() { println("first w/o lambda")}
```

To call them:

```
first().invoke()
firstWithoutLambda().invoke()
```

which will print the messages that you would expect.

From the original Kotlin tutorial a good article: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
first()()
```

or

```
first().invoke()
```

`first` returns a function, it does not invoke it.